# Laptop not booting

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader, boot-repair, grub-efi

I've got a Vaio laptop that used to work with 13.10. I did an upgrade to 14.04 and since then it does not want to boot any more, that is it doesn't seem to reach grub: I'm stuck on a "BIOS" screen telling me "Windows (sic) failed to load : recovery solution, contact vaio,..."

Running boot-repair does not help (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7309686/)

I wiped out my SSD and did a fresh install of 14.04 (default options) : nope.
Also tried fresh install 13.10 : nope (even though boot-repair tells me "no error" this time)

I tried Fedora : success!! (but I'd prefer Ubuntu)

I tried 14.10 again but using a Legacy boot this time instead of UEFI : success but it takes 14s to boot compared to the previous 3s! That's not really satisfying!

My questions:

- by "wipe out" I mean delete MBR and GPT informations by writing 0s on the disk (dd if=/dev/zero ...). Could it be an issue?
- any ways to know what's wrong during the boot process BEFORE grub is started?
- can it be related to a BIOS/EFI bug in the firmware?
- Any idea what could be the problem?

**Update : **

I checked where grub was installed but I couldn't find it (see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/259086/how-do-you-non-destructively-check-if-grub2-is-installed-in-the-boot-sector-or-i) ) ?! I dumped the 512k at start of the disk and ... there are all 0s !? It should contain grub no?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If by "512k at start of the disk" you mean 440 bytes, then no, GRUB should not reside there on an EFI-booting computer. On such a computer, the boot loader lives in the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) as ordinary file(s). You've got such a partition (`/dev/sda1`), but there's no evidence of GRUB installed on it. You may want to check that manually using an emergency system -- look for a directory called `EFI/ubuntu` on that partition. On an Ubuntu install, it will normally have a file called `grubx64.efi`, and probably another called `shimx64.efi`. If those files aren't present, then your EFI boot loader has failed to install. In this case, you have a number of options:

- Install GRUB manually. This can be done with emergency discs, using the procedure described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) (although that's a rather inefficient procedure).
- Install GRUB automatically. The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool can *usually* fix this problem relatively painlessly; however, you must be sure to boot it *in EFI mode.* Once you've booted, check for the presence of a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode and may proceed. If not, then you should check how you boot and find a way to boot into EFI mode. (Unfortunately, how to do this varies from one system to another, so I can't provide a simple set of instructions.)
- Use my [rEFInd boot manager:](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Download a USB flash drive or CD-R image, prepare the medium, and boot with it. You should see at least one option to boot Ubuntu. If it works, install the Debian-package version of rEFInd. It will then take over boot manager duties from GRUB.